# How to fetch own best score using gameNetwork.request( "loadScores" )?

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

does someone use gameNetwork provided by Google Play? Im having a little problem with it, im trying to fetch personal best score and its not working well.
Here is the code that i use

```
            function loadScoreCallback(event)
                oldScore = event.data[5].formattedValue
            end

            gameNetwork.request( "loadScores",
            {
                leaderboard =
                {
                    category = "thecategory id", 
                    playerScope = "Global",   -- Global, FriendsOnly
                    timeScope = "AllTime",    -- AllTime, Week, Today
                    range = {1,5},
                    playerCentered = true,
                },
                listener = loadScoreCallback
            })
```

I also tried something like

```
                function loadScoreCallback(event)
                oldScore = event.data
            end

            gameNetwork.request( "loadScores",
            {
                leaderboard =
                {
                    playerID = playerName,
                    category = "CgkIptXi1qgCEAIQAw",
                    playerScope = "Global",   -- Global, FriendsOnly
                    timeScope = "AllTime",    -- AllTime, Week, Today
                    playerCentered = true,
                },
                listener = loadScoreCallback
            })
```

Also didnt work :/

Comment: How does it 'not work?' Does it throw an error? Does it not call the callback?

Comment: Well if i put it in a text, it crashes the text. It just doesnt show up. I need a fetch for one person and that just doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some trouble figuring this out, but I found a solution that works for me.
this is the listener that is called when the user submits a score.

```
   local function onGameNetworkRequestResult( event )
       if event.type == "setHighScore" then
        local function tempScoresFct(event)
            if event.data then
              local playerRank = event.data[1].rank
              local currentValue = event.data[1].value
              if lb.tempScore <= event.data[1].value then
                native.showAlert("Score submitted", "You score is lower or equal than your current score in the leaderboard("..currentValue.."), nothing changed. Your global, all time rank is:\n" .. playerRank .. "\nTo see how you are doing among your friends and in other time scales, click the button \"show leaderboard\".", {"Ok"})
              else
                native.showAlert("Score submitted", "Your score was successfully uploaded to the leaderboard. Your global, all time rank is:\n" .. playerRank .. "\nTo see how you are doing among your friends and in other time scales, click the button \"show leaderboard\".", {"Ok"})
              end
            end
          end

          gameNetwork.request( "loadScores",
          {
            leaderboard =
            {
              category = event.data.category,
              playerScope = "Global",   -- Global, FriendsOnly
              timeScope = "AllTime",    -- AllTime, Week, Today
              range = {1,1}, --Just get one player 
              playerCentered = true, -- and this player is the player that is logged in
            },
            listener = tempScoresFct
          })
 end
end
```

and this ist the function that submits the score:

```
function lb.submitScoreFct(event)
  if event.phase == "ended" then

    if gameNetwork.request("isConnected") then
      --show leaderboards
      print("submitting score")

      local myCategory
      local categoryName
      if event.target.category == 1 then
        myCategory = "ategoryID" --palo alto
        categoryName = "Palo Alto"
      elseif event.target.category == 2 then
        myCategory = "ategoryID" --groningen
        categoryName = "Groningen"
      elseif event.target.category == 3 then
        myCategory = "ategoryID" --sp2
        categoryName = "SP2"
      end
      --local score = mRand(100,1000)
      local score = event.target.score
      lb.tempScore = score -- i use this to verify if the uploaded score was higher or lower then the value that is already there
      print("Added " .. score .. " to " .. categoryName)

      gameNetwork.request( "setHighScore",
      {
        localPlayerScore = { category=myCategory, value=tonumber(score) },
        listener = lb.onGameNetworkRequestResult
      })
    end
  else
    print("user needs to log in")
    -- Tries to login the user, if there is a problem then it will try to resolve it. eg. Show the log in screen.
    gameNetwork.request("login",
    {
      listener = loginListener,
      userInitiated = true -- if that is false, than this process is silent ie dont pop up a log in if the user is not logged in
    })
  end
  return true
end
```

Oh and one thing I figured out, is that this listener functions are fragile. If there is one error inside, they quit and sometimes dont give any error.
For example if you try to print(event.data.rank) (instedt of print(event.data[1].rank)) there is no error but the function ends at this point and the rest of the function is not executed...

Answer (score 0):

Well so i found a better idea, since not everyone is online all the time i made my own saving system, and it fetches high score from there. But i still dont know why it doesnt work, well at least i solved it with this.